Points disappear after applying rule based symbology (QGIS Maidenhead)
Trying to colour points by a field I have in a shapefile. The data field I'm interested in is called "main_commo"
I've put in the 3 rules (in this format: "main_commo" = 'LEAD') for the 3 minerals I need (Pb, Au, Sn) and changed them to how I want, but when I click apply they disappear. They return if I go to single symbol.
Can anyone suggest some help? I did not create the shapefile, I extracted it from a geospatial database online. I'm hoping a few people have ideas from experiencing this, I apologise but even though the spatia data can be found online, my work specific AOI is private.

You probably have made some error when setting your rule but without the whole rule setting it's hard to say. Could you post a picture of one of your rule setting ?

Try setting a Categorized styling with the main_commo field as Value. To make sure that is working. Are you sure there are no leading or trailing whitespaces, like ' LEAD'or 'LEAD '?



Hopefully you guys can see them. One is rule based, one is categorised. They both make them disappear.
The filter test returns features, but when I click count features it comes up as 0.
